# Using WIC to reproduce WPF BitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth / Height

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, wic

I need to generate thumbnails of "huge" image files without loading the full image in memory.
This feature is perfectly implemented in WPF's [BitmapImage.DecodePixelWidth / Height](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelheight?view=netframework-4.7.2) but i need to use it in a non-managed C++ dll.

I "think" it is implemented using WIC, however i cannot find any useful sample about this functionality, i would load all the thumbnail formats that WIC can handle.

Anyone can help about it?

Comment: Just a note, the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.decodepixelwidth?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) on MS Docs say that *The JPEG and Portable Network Graphics (PNG) codecs natively decode the image to the specified size; other codecs decode the image at its original size and scale the image to the desired size*. So it may not be "perfect" for all image formats.

Comment: What would your program do? What input, output do you expect?

Comment: I would input an image filename, and output an uncompressed bitmap (pixel array in RGBA or RGB format) of the desired size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two of the WIC codecs ([JPEG and JPEG-XR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmapsourcetransform-getclosestsize#remarks)) support scaling within the decoder, and you can verify this at runtime using `IWICBitmapSourceTransform::GetClosestSize`.  However, even if the source image must be decoded at its full resolution, `IWICBitmapScaler` will use minimal memory when scaling the image to its desired size, as indicated in the documentation's [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincodec/nn-wincodec-iwicbitmapscaler#remarks).

Better still, `IWICBitmapScaler` will automatically use the `IWICBitmapSourceTransform` capability of the decoder when supported, so you can simply use it and get the behavior you seek automatically.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have a code snippet with proper steps that would help me?

Comment: This sample from the docs has the basic usage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wic/-wic-bitmapsources-howto-scale